# Undo Revert Commit in Azure-DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I had merged a development branch into my ticket branch for which a commit `Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'` was created. There were some confusions, so I had to revert this commit in Azure DevOps using the revert option. For this, 2 commits are created - first `Revert Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'`(PR #123) and then `Merged PR #123 Revert Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'`(PR #123). In Dev-Ops the commits are shown in the following order:

```
    Commits                                                                      PR
    --------                                                                    ----
(1) Merged PR #123 Revert Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'  123
(2) Revert Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'                 123
(3) Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'
.....
....
```

Now, because some clarity in my previous doubts, I want to re-revert my last commit My question is which commit should I revert - 1 or 2? Note that both shows the same file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `git revert` you specify the commit that you want to **undo** the changes of. Git does that by creating a new revert commit.

So if you want to undo your last commit changes, which happens to be the revert commit you will run `git revert Merged PR #123 Revert Merge branch 'develop/branchname' into 'ticketbranch'` **(make sure to specify the `SHA` of the commit and not the title)**

You can also do `git revert HEAD` and it will undo the commit changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply https://stackoverflow.com/users/11485794/nadar. Also, one more thing, we need to provide the parent no while writing the revert commit(in case of a merge revert merge commit), this link describes it clearly https://tilns.herokuapp.com/posts/962b8d3fc2-reverting-a-merge-commit